# Как это работает?

Tags: c++

есть программа:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  float volume = 0;
  std::string command = "";

  std::cin >> command;

  if (command == "vol"){
    std::cin >> volume;
  }

  std::cout << "Entered volume=" << volume;
}
```

если ввести не vol а потом допустим 58, а сразу vol 58 то проверка пройдет успешно, и заранее в пременную volume введется значение. Это как?

Comment: В плюсах не шарю, но по логике: программа ожидает команду, если команда `vol`, то ожидает значение, а так вы сразу оба условия выполнили

Comment: @DaemonHK но строка ведь vol 58 а не vol, и условие не должно выполнятся!

Comment: А при чем здесь "строка"? С чего вы взяли, что чтение идет построчно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::cin >> command;
```

читает **одно слово**, а именно ваше `vol`.

Для чтения всей строки используйте функцию `getline`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin`, используя `operator<<`, читает из потока ввода до того, как встретит пробел (условий, на самом деле, больше, подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2)). Всё, что после пробела остаётся в буфере и может быть считано повторным вызовом этого оператора.

Можно читать всю строку до `\n`, с использованием [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline), либо же отбрасывать ненужные части буфера с помощью [`ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).